# Avoid unseemly coefficient name when running regression

Tags: r, dplyr, lm, purrr

I run the following regressions using the `map2` function:

```
map2(listOfInvVolWeightedOtherStratPortfolioReturns,listOfValueAndMomentumFactorReturns,~lm((.y %>% select(-date) %>% as.matrix()) ~ (.x %>% select(-date) %>% as.matrix())) %>% summary())
```

The coefficient name for each reg in the list of reg outputs is `.x %>% select(-date) %>% as.matrix()`:

```
                                            Estimate
(Intercept)                               0.01244429
.x %>% select(-date) %>% as.matrix()     -0.81570351
```

How can I set the name of the coefficients, lets say to `factor`, when I run the regressions to avoid this?

Comment: Crazy idea: Don't create one of these tidyverse tapeworms and write some R code that is (i) easier to read and (ii) easier to debug, and also solves this issue easily. I appreciate that some people find magrittr chains more readable but this is clearly not such a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reprex this is tough but the following is more readable and I believe it should work:

```
myFun <- function(x, y) {
  x <- x %>%
    select(-date) %>%
    as.matrix()
  y <- y %>%
    select(-date) %>%
    as.matrix()
  res <- lm(y ~ x) %>%
    summary()
  return(res)
}
map2(listOfInvVolWeightedOtherStratPortfolioReturns,
     listOfValueAndMomentumFactorReturns,
     myFun)
```